# NullReferenceException in Brand New Project

Tags: c#, opengl, visual-studio-2012, nullreferenceexception, monogame

- EDIT:  Perhaps someone could copy and paste it into their Virtual
  Studio and see if its just on my end that it is not working?

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012 with MonoGame and a OpenGL template.  Every project, even projects which are created brand new and untouched, are all getting the `NullReferenceException was Unhandled` error.  I do not know how this could be, as these projects are merely created and then run.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Call Stack:

```
>   DeleteMe.exe!DeleteMe.Program.Main() Line 22    C#
    [External Code]
```

**The code has been unchanged from the time the project was created.**

Program.cs:

```
#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
#endregion

namespace DeleteMe
{
#if WINDOWS || LINUX
    /// <summary>
    /// The main class.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var game = new Game1())
                game.Run();
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Game1.cs:

```
#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
#endregion

namespace DeleteMe
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public Game1()
            : base()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `game()` code.

Comment: It is the untouched default, but sure.

Comment: I removed it to keep the post clean.  If someone else wants it back, I will. But it is the default project, so I don't know if it would be helpful.

Comment: You could pastebin it, and either way there's a size limit on SO, so it'll just get a scrollbar. The information you've given us isn't enough though.

Comment: Very well. I will post all of code.

Comment: What does the Stack trace look like?

Comment: posted the Call Stack.  Is that the right thing?

Comment: Check build type... 32 or 64-bit? Try switching it and see what happens.

Comment: @tnw how do i do that? :) I thought Visual Studio was only available in 32 bit

Comment: @Evorlor https://www.google.com/search?q=studio+2012+build+type&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS566US566&oq=studio+2012+build+type&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.2836j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @tnw according to google, there is no such thing as a "build type" for a visual studio project

Comment: @Evorlor You can be pedantic if you'd like, but if you click the first link you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: @tnw x86.  Only option its showing.

Comment: @Evorlor I don't think you even read the first link on Google. Please read it, you need to create a new build definition.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\`

Run `oalinst.exe`